# Getting errors compiling in cmd but not netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, compiler-errors, cmd

I'm trying to compile a Java class file in cmd with javac but it keeps giving me these errors:

```
Jukebox.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<Song> jSongs;

  symbol:    class Song
  location:  class Jukebox
```

All of the errors I'm getting are pointing to the Song class (all files are in the same folder if that means anything) except when I'm using NetBeans, the file compiles just fine. The problem is this is a project and whoever is marking it is going to try compile it with cmd. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below you'll find the Song class (which compiles fine in cmd) and then the Jukebox class (the one with the problem).

```
public class Song {
    private String artist;
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private int playCount;
    private double length;

    public Song()
    {
        artist = "unknown";
        title = "unknown";
        price = 0.00;
        length = 0.00;
        playCount = 0;
    }

    public Song(String artist, String title, double price, double length)
    {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.length = length;
        playCount = 0;
    }

    public String getArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return playCount;
    }

    public double getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void changePrice(double newPrice)
    {
        price = newPrice;
    }

    public void playSong()
    {
        playCount++;
        System.out.println(title + " is now playing." + "\n" + toString());
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return artist + "\n"
        + title + "\n"
        + price + "\n"
        + length;
    }
}
```

And the Jukebox class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Jukebox {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Song> jSongs;

    public Jukebox()
    {
        name = "Primary Jukebox";
        jSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double calcTotal()
    {
        double total = 0.00;

        for (int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++)
        {
            total += jSongs.get(i).getPrice();
        }

        return total;
    }

    public void searchSong(String sTitle)
    {
        boolean check = false;
        if ( jSongs.size() == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("The are no songs in the list.");
            check = true;
        } else if ( jSongs.size() != 0 ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
                if ( jSongs.get(i).getTitle().equals(sTitle) == true ) {
                    check = true;
                    System.out.println(jSongs.get(i));
                    jSongs.get(i).playSong();
                }
            }
        }
        if ( check == false ) {
            System.out.println("The searched song could not be found.");
        }
    }

    public Song searchArtist(String sArtist)
    {
        int countMatch = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++) {
            if ( jSongs.get(i).getArtist().equals(sArtist) ) {
                countMatch++;
                return jSongs.get(i);
            } else if ( countMatch == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("The requested artist could not be found.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addSong(Song s1)
    {
        boolean check = false;

        if ( jSongs.size() == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Your song will be added to the list.");
            jSongs.add(s1);
            return;
        } else if ( jSongs.size() != 0 ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
                if ( jSongs.get(i) == s1 ) {
                    check = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( check == false ) {
            System.out.println("Your song will be added to the list.");
            jSongs.add(s1);
        } else if ( check == true ) {
            System.out.println("Your song is already in the list.");
        }
    }

    public void removeSong(String title)
    {
        boolean check = false;
        for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( jSongs.get(i).getTitle().equals(title) ) {
                jSongs.remove(i);
                check = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(check);
    }

    public void displaySongs()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(jSongs.get(i));
        }
    }

    public Song showMostExpensive()
    {
        double price = 0.00;
        Song mostESong = new Song();
        for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( jSongs.get(i).getPrice() > price ) {
                price = jSongs.get(i).getPrice();
                mostESong = jSongs.get(i);
            }
        }
        return mostESong;
    }

    public Song showShortest()
    {
        double length = 500.00;
        Song shortest = new Song();
        for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( jSongs.get(i).getLength() < length ) {
                length = jSongs.get(i).getLength();
                shortest = jSongs.get(i);
            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }

    public Song mostPlayed()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Song mostPSong = new Song();
        for ( int i = 0; i < jSongs.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( jSongs.get(i).getCount() > count ) {
                count = jSongs.get(i).getCount();
                mostPSong = jSongs.get(i);
            }
        }
        return mostPSong;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mention `-cp` while compiling in cmd?

Comment: I've never heard of -cp before?

Comment: `java -help` ----> `-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.`

Comment: I should mention I know very little about Java and that just confuses me more.

Comment: In other words: you need to specify the entire classpath from the command line, otherwise the compiler won't know where to find all the classes it needs.

Comment: What is your package statement?

Comment: Oh dear how do I do that? javac -classpath (location) ?

Comment: But in NetBeans everything is fine, it's giving me no errors. Only cmd is giving me the cannot find symbol error. Also I have no idea what a package statement is or how to use one.

Comment: log the command you are running and also the folder in which you are running

Comment: This is the folder where the files are located:

C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Jukebox

I'm not sure I know what you mean by what command I'm running?

Comment: If you are a beginner start from [basic](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) and also read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: See I haven't had this problem with cmd before, I could compile this file in college without configuring anything yet I can't from my own computer.

Comment: 1/ @Michael_D make sure there is no **package foo;** statement in both the files

2/ RUN the following commands: 
**cd C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Jukebox;
javac Jukebox.java**

Comment: C:\>cd C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Jukebox; javac Jukebox.java didn't work, says it can't find the path specified.

Comment: If it compiles in NetBeans I can't understand why it won't compile in cmd.

Comment: @Michael_D some code is missing from Jukebox.java
As per error **private ArrayList<Song> jSongs;** should be 10th line but its 4th in the given code you pasted above.....
I think package statement is missing ??

Comment: Yeah I don't have a package statement. I read that I shouldn't need one since all files are in the same location?